# Matlab integration - Run and test Matlab VOLTTRON Integration - pyzmq error+ volltron/config. path

Tags: volttron

Below the steps followed to integrate a fake building - fake modbus device (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) with matlab-based interface.

Following the documentation steps at: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/devguides/walkthroughs/DrivenMatlabAgent-Walkthrough.html

## Installation steps for system running Matlab:

- Install python (my Python versions: 3.6.3 and 2.7.12)
- Install pyzmq following the steps at (https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq): I use  `pip install pyzmq`
  I get
  `Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in ./env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

## Steps for system running Matlab:

- Install python –  done
- Install pyzmq –done
- Install Matlab-- done (R2017b)

run `pyversion` --done

```
   version: '2.7'
   executable: '/home/USER_NAME/volttron/env/bin/python'
   library: 'libpython2.7.so.1.0'
   home: '/home/USER_NAME/volttron/env'
   isloaded: 0
```

when I run `py.zmq.pyzmq_version()` I get

```
ans = 

Python str with no properties.

15.4.0
```

I copied the example.m to the desktop.

## Run and test Matlab VOLTTRON Integration:

To run and test the integration:
Assumptions

Device driver agent is already developed (master_driveragent-3.1.1- is installed)

## Installation:

- Install VOLTTRON –done
- Add subtree volttron-applications under volttron/applications by using the following command –

For adding subtree: I used the code:
`git subtree add --prefix applications https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron-   applications.git develop --squash`
error 
(**Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.**)

## Configuration

Copy example configuration file applications/pnnl/DrivenMatlabAgent/config_waterheater to **volltron/config.** (I could not find a path called config?)

**Questions**

- Please is there any issue in **pyzmq** ?
- In the volttron root I run the subtree command, why it is not accepting to add the **subtree**?
- What is the volltron/config. path?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have you have local changes in your cloned volttron directory. Please stash or commit those changes before adding subtree.

If config folder does not exists you can create it (I will make a note of it in the documentation as well) It is only a location to copy the config file to make changes ( config_url and data_url )